# Questions about require and DB instances

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm using Sequel and I'm trying to use the Models association that Sequel provides, basically to link a class to a model in Sequel.

My class is defined as this:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite(dbname)

class Page < Sequel::Model; end
```

My main file calls this class in a separate file, and tries to instantiate a page object:

```
page = Page[id]
```

When I run this, I get an exception `SQLite3::IOException: disk I/O error`.

I have two questions. In my main file:

- do I need to `require 'sequel'`? It's already required in the Page class file.
- do I need to also connect to the DB, or is it not necessary as the DB connection is already defined in the class itself?

PS: if I do everything inside a single file, I don't have any I/O exception. I wonder if it's linked to the fact that I do everything in separate files.

Comment: Do you have a place, where your db is stored? And btw your app maybe have similar structure as sinatra apps, you can look up there.

Comment: It isn't necessary to tell us that you are *not* using Rails. The tags you used tell us that. Also, it's recommended to not use "Sequel: " to start the title. If you can work it into the title naturally that's fine, but don't just tack it on as, again, the tags used will suffice.

Comment: Thank you @oleksandr-verhun. Yes my DB is stored and functional. I'll take a look at Sinatra to see how they handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer for the two specific questions I was asking:

1. We don't need to `require sequel` in the file that calls the class which implements the Model from Sequel.
2. We don't need to connect to the DB in this same file. The DB is called in the class itself.